# How to convert Timestamp to Date format in DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `DataFrame` with `Timestamp` column, which i need to convert as `Date` format.

Is there any Spark SQL functions available for this?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can `cast` the column to date:

Scala:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DateType

val newDF = df.withColumn("dateColumn", df("timestampColumn").cast(DateType))
```

Pyspark:

```py
df = df.withColumn('dateColumn', df['timestampColumn'].cast('date'))
```

Comment: This isn't Spark SQL.

Comment: @dslack This solution uses functions available as part of the Spark SQL package, but it doesn't use the SQL language, instead it uses the robust DataFrame API, with SQL-like functions, instead of using less reliable strings with actual SQL queries.

Comment: What is less reliable about SQL queries?

Comment: @dslack well, it all depends on the application. In general, if you goal is to produce a reliable and testable stable codebase, query strings are not very recommended, because they are harder to change, it's easier to make simple mistakes and it's less modularizable.

Comment: Need help. reading Data from the database via jdbc. Oracle table has 15-DEC-2016 as a field with DATE datatype. Dataframe.printSchema() shows Timestamp. but when i print it, it shows all nulls.

Comment: @RudreshAjgaonkar One possible workaround is to cast the date to string when reading from the source database, then converting to TimestampType in Spark with unix_timestamp or an equivalent strategy.

Answer (score 21):

In SparkSQL:

```
SELECT
  CAST(the_ts AS DATE) AS the_date
FROM the_table
```

Answer (score 6):

Imagine the following input:

```
val dataIn = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
        (1, "some data"),
        (2, "more data")))
    .toDF("id", "stuff")
    .withColumn("ts", current_timestamp())

dataIn.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- stuff: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ts: timestamp (nullable = false)
```

You can use the [to_date](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#to_date(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) function:

```
val dataOut = dataIn.withColumn("date", to_date($"ts"))

dataOut.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- stuff: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ts: timestamp (nullable = false)
 |-- date: date (nullable = false)

dataOut.show(false)
+---+---------+-----------------------+----------+
|id |stuff    |ts                     |date      |
+---+---------+-----------------------+----------+
|1  |some data|2017-11-21 16:37:15.828|2017-11-21|
|2  |more data|2017-11-21 16:37:15.828|2017-11-21|
+---+---------+-----------------------+----------+
```

I would recommend preferring these methods over casting and plain SQL.

Answer (score 4):

For Spark 2.4+,

```
import spark.implicits._
val newDF = df.withColumn("dateColumn", $"timestampColumn".cast(DateType))
```

OR

```
val newDF = df.withColumn("dateColumn", col("timestampColumn").cast(DateType))
```

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to use..tried and tested -

```
df_join_result.withColumn('order_date', df_join_result['order_date'].cast('date'))
```