# Convert timestamp to date in Spark dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've seen (here: [How to convert Timestamp to Date format in DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656001/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-date-format-in-dataframe)) the way to convert a timestamp in datetype, but,at least for me, it doesn't work.

Here is what I've tried:

```
# Create dataframe
df_test = spark.createDataFrame([('20170809',), ('20171007',)], ['date',])

# Convert to timestamp
df_test2 = df_test.withColumn('timestamp',func.when((df_test.date.isNull() | (df_test.date == '')) , '0')\
.otherwise(func.unix_timestamp(df_test.date,'yyyyMMdd')))\

# Convert timestamp to date again
df_test2.withColumn('date_again', df_test2['timestamp'].cast(stypes.DateType())).show()
```

But this returns null in the column `date_again`:

```
+--------+----------+----------+
|    date| timestamp|date_again|
+--------+----------+----------+
|20170809|1502229600|      null|
|20171007|1507327200|      null|
+--------+----------+----------+
```

Any idea of what's failing?

Comment: I would go with `df_test2.withColumn('date_again', from_unixtime('timestamp', 'yyyyMMdd')).show()` (or whatever format you prefer). Probably some type of a dupe of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format

Comment: i have my unix-timestamps of varying lenghts, 11, 12, 13, 15, and sometimes 16. I just need the hours-mins-secs-days-month-year information to be extracted from the unix-timestamps, and not the miliseconds info. How do I process the unix-timestamps to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Following:

```
func.when((df_test.date.isNull() | (df_test.date == '')) , '0')\
  .otherwise(func.unix_timestamp(df_test.date,'yyyyMMdd'))
```

doesn't work because it is type inconsistent - the first clause returns `string` while the second clause returns `bigint`. As a result it will always return `NULL` if `data` is `NOT NULL` and not empty.

It is also obsolete - SQL functions are `NULL` and malformed format safe. There is no need for additional checks.

```
In [1]: spark.sql("SELECT unix_timestamp(NULL, 'yyyyMMdd')").show()
+----------------------------------------------+
|unix_timestamp(CAST(NULL AS STRING), yyyyMMdd)|
+----------------------------------------------+
|                                          null|
+----------------------------------------------+


In [2]: spark.sql("SELECT unix_timestamp('', 'yyyyMMdd')").show()
+--------------------------+
|unix_timestamp(, yyyyMMdd)|
+--------------------------+
|                      null|
+--------------------------+
```

And you don't need intermediate step in Spark 2.2 or later:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date

to_date("date", "yyyyMMdd")
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I updated recently to 2.2 and wasn't aware about to_date.

Comment: `"date"` should be `col("date")`, otherwise it is casting a string reproducing null.
Therefore needs to import also `col` from the `functions`.
The format of the date is an [optional parameter](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=date#pyspark.sql.functions.to_date).

Answer (score 18):

you should be doing the following

```
>>> df_test2.withColumn('date_again', func.from_unixtime('timestamp').cast(DateType())).show()
+--------+----------+----------+
|    date| timestamp|date_again|
+--------+----------+----------+
|20170809|1502216100|2017-08-09|
|20171007|1507313700|2017-10-07|
+--------+----------+----------+
```

and schema is

```
>>> df_test2.withColumn('date_again', func.from_unixtime('timestamp').cast(DateType())).printSchema()
root
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date_again: date (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem was the type inconsistency that mentions @user8371915 in his comment, applying again `from_unixtime` solves it

Comment: Where is `DateType()` coming from? Also what can we do to have Datetime output compared to Date alone!

Answer (score 8):

For pyspark:

*Assume* you have a field name: *'DateTime'* that shows the date *as a date and a time*

Add a new field to your *df* that shows a *'DateOnly'* column as follows:

```
 from pyspark.sql.functions  import date_format
    df.withColumn("DateOnly", date_format('DateTime', "yyyyMMdd")).show()
```

This will show a new column in the *df* called *DateOnly*- with the date in *yyyymmdd* form

Answer (score 3):

To convert a `unix_timestamp` column (called `TIMESTMP`) in a pyspark dataframe (`df`)  --  to a `Date` type:

Below is a two step process (there may be a shorter way):

- convert from UNIX timestamp to `timestamp`
- convert from `timestamp` to `Date`

Initially the `df.printShchema()` shows:  `-- TIMESTMP: long (nullable = true)`

use `spark.SQL` to implement the conversion as follows:

```
df.registerTempTable("dfTbl")

dfNew= spark.sql("""
                     SELECT *, cast(TIMESTMP as Timestamp) as newTIMESTMP 
                     FROM dfTbl d
                  """)

dfNew.printSchema()
```

the printSchema() will show:

```
-- newTIMESTMP: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

finally convert the type from `timestamp` to `Date` as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType
dfNew=dfNew.withColumn('actual_date', dfNew['newTIMESTMP'].cast(DateType()))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#udf to convert the ts to timestamp
get_timestamp = udf(lambda x : datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x/ 1000.0).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

#apply this udf in the dataframe with your timestamp
df_withdate = df.withColumn("datetime", get_timestamp(df.ts))
```

Comment: Although it may seem alright and work, it is best to avoid using UDFs as long as a spark-native solution exists. This would become a bottleneck when applied to a large data set.

Comment: Sure, we can simply add the logic in the withColumn code as well.

Answer (score 0):

they closed my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66118658/how-to-convert-a-unix-timestamp-column-in-a-human-comprehensible-timestamp-in-py) as duplicate of this one so I'll copy and paste my answer here (is a duplicate, right?)

As the timestamp column is in milliseconds is just necessary to convert into seconds and cast it into `TimestampType` and that should do the trick:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.select( 
      (F.col("my_timestamp") / 1000).cast(TimestampType())
)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option without `import TimestampType`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

F.from_unixtime(F.col('date_col') / 1000).cast('date')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly cast the field:

```
df = df.withColumn('datetime', col('timestamp').cast(TimestampType()))
```